# Why action is perform multiple time after loading is finish and why it queuing all the events?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, touch

While loading when we click on back button or any cell of the table the action is called multiple times after loading is finish.Here the the code snippet that what i'm doing when I start the loading and stop the loading.

```
+(void)showLoader_OnView{
      APP_DELEGATE.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
     [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:APP_DELEGATE.window animated:YES];
}
```

To stop the loading:-

```
+(void)hideLoader {
    APP_DELEGATE.window.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:APP_DELEGATE.window animated:YES];
}
```

please help me.

**Update**

actually i'm taking data from server. whenever user will go to next window then in viewWillAppear function i call a function which will hit the api to get the data.

```
-(void)performAutoSync
{
    @try
    {
        if(self.shouldPerformAutoSync)//Necessary conditions to check the auto sync
        {
            [AppConstants showLoader_OnView];  //here i call the loader.
            self.shouldPerformAutoSync  = NO;
            if(!self.isSyncing)
            {
                if(!syncBl)
                {
                    syncBl = [[SyncBL alloc] init];
                    syncBl.delegate = self;
                }

                if(!syncDl)
                    syncDl = [[SyncDL alloc] init];

                //            [self saveModifiedDataForCurrentViewController];


                [self delayToAutoSync];


                NSMutableDictionary *dictMainData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
                [dictMainData setObject:[syncDl fetchCompleteDataAndPrepareDictionary:YES] forKey:@"data"];//@"MainData"];
                [syncBl performAutoSync:dictMainData];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        BILog(@"%@",exception);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to add   APP_DELEGATE.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO; It is automatically disables ui with      [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:APP_DELEGATE.window animated:YES]; Please provide your service call codes

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't tell anything about the problem you are facing. You should give more details if you want people understand your issue and help you to solve it.

Comment: i have updated my question please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't block the main thread.**

Seeing that you invoke `[AppConstants showLoader_OnView]` from `performAutoSync`, and that `showLoader_OnView` in turn executes:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:APP_DELEGATE.window animated:YES]
```

I can only assume that `performAutoSync` is executed in the main thread. This, of course, blocks the UI until your operations are completed.

---

You should redesign so that you won't need all your state variables, globals, global calls, and take advantage of multi-threading.

Also, remove this, as it qualifies as a kludge;

```
APP_DELEGATE.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

Comment: Did you use something in the form `performSelectorInBackground` ?

Comment: No actually i used `GCD` to run  `[syncBl performAutoSync:dictMainData];` function in background thread. This is the function that i'm using to get the data from the server( i.e for Async operation ). I have less experience in iPhone development so that's why i don't know about the `performSelectorInBackground`. How can i do this by using this.